# Angular compiler warnings with Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am seeing lots of warnings with bootstrap in my Angular11 application.

```
WARNING: You probably don't mean to use the color value gray in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as gray, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "gray").
If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $state'.

  ╷
4 │   .list-group-item-#{$state} {
  │                      ^^^^^^
  ╵
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_list-group.scss 4:22  list-group-item-variant()
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_list-group.scss 148:3        @import
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 35:9           @import
    src/app/scss/application.scss 4:9                         root stylesheet
```

Bootstrap import

```
 "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
```

Would be great if I could fix / mute these. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Following the discuss [here on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29219) my problem resolved when i put double-quotes on my sass-map.

I don't know how your *application.scss* looks like, but maybe you have also a sass map looking like this:

```
$...-colors: (
    ...
    gray: $gray,
    ...
);
```

Change it to:

```
$...-colors: (
    ...
    "gray": $gray,
    ...
);
```

You can also check the [sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#advanced-variable-functions) for further help